# Mouse cursor does not disappear if moving while loading scene - OpenGL and GLFW

Tags: opengl, mouse, glfw

I am designing a toy Game Engine with OpenGL 4.1, Xcode, and GLFW. I have noticed that if I move the mouse while the scene is loading, the mouse cursor does not disappear, despite the call

```
glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_CURSOR, GLFW_CURSOR_DISABLED);
```

The game works fine, but the cursor remains visible.

I tried to put the glfwSetInputMode() call after the scene is loaded, right before entering the game loop, but it didn't help. Also, enabling the cursor and disabling it again does not affect its presence on the screen. How can I fix this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Cursor is not a OpenGL feature, this is underlying OS graphical system feature. GLFW library provides you with cross-platform system API wrapper.

According to the GLWF API:

> > GLFW_CURSOR_HIDDEN makes the cursor invisible when it is over the client area of the window but does not restrict the cursor from leaving.

When

> > GLFW_CURSOR_DISABLED hides and grabs the cursor, providing virtual and unlimited cursor movement. This is useful for implementing for example 3D camera controls.

So `GLFW_CURSOR_DISABLED` is useful in full-screen mode, when `GLFW_CURSOR_HIDDEN` is useful in windowing mode.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear. The game works perfectly. However, if and only if I move the mouse while loading, then the cursor does not disappear.
Of course I tried your suggestion and double checked the GLFW official guide before answering.

Comment: I suppose when you are loading the scene, OpenGL context is not yet initialized, please check it.

Comment: Hi Victor. It is initialized. if(!glfwInit()) is the first instruction in my code. And no, I don't need the GLFW_CURSOR_HIDDEN option, but the GLFW_CURSOR_DISABLED option, which works perfectly as long as I don't move the mouse while the application is running. If I used GLFW_CURSOR_HIDDEN I would need to mouse over the window in order to capture it, whereas what I want is that the mouse is captured wherever the cursor is located at the moment I run the app, which is what happens with GLFW_CURSOR_DISABLED. So, I think, your conclusion is incorrect.

Comment: window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "mywindow", NULL, NULL); glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_CURSOR, GLFW_CURSOR_DISABLED);  /*load scene*/ glfwShowWindow(window); ???

Comment: Yes, everything is there, much before capturing the mouse. Actually, I don't have a glfwShowWindow()...

Comment: I've also tried to disconnect the external monitor or calling the glfwSetInputMode() function somewhere else in the code, but that's not helping. I have also added a glfwShowWindow(window) call, but still, same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this same problem and I managed to find a solution that worked for me. After much poking around I found that as long as I made sure to call `glfwPollEvents()` at least once before disabling the cursor I'd be good. Hopefully this helps someone.